# Send the search query of a form as a GA event

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

I'd like to send any user-input data submitted from a `<form />` to Google Analytics so I can do things such as see the most frequently searched terms etc. I'm familiar with sending events, but not sure how to include arbitrary user data in a way that they're properly parsed by GA and can be filtered/sorted/analyzed.

The HTML would be the following:

```js
// I use Vue but any vanilla JS solution would work
```

```html
<!-- Google Analytics -->
<script>
(function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
(i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
})(window,document,'script','https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

ga('create', 'UA-XXXXX-Y', 'auto');
ga('send', 'pageview');
</script>
<!-- End Google Analytics -->

<input type="text" placeholder="search for something" />
<button type="submit">search</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Send the information with one or more events, adding the input content in the event label.

Comment: do you mind providing an example of some kind of implementation? many thanks